How to order dataframe based on substrings in column?
I have a dataframe with string rows. I want to sort the entire dataframe based on the strings in this column. However, there are some rows that contains a substring that is the text in another row so it is messing up the order. My dataframe looks like:
  col1           col2        col3       col4
Animal           Tiger       Cat         Dog
Name             Adam       Grace       Julia
Street Name1    Pine St    Crown St    Palm Ave
Street Name2    Grey St    Tree St     New St
Color           Green        Blue       Yellow
Interest         Yes         No           Yes
Low Interest     No          No           Yes
High Interest    Yes         No           Yes
City2             x          z             y
City1             m          r             t

I want to sort it so it looks like:
  col1           col2        col3       col4
Name             Adam       Grace       Julia
Street Name1    Pine St    Crown St    Palm Ave
Street Name2    Grey St    Tree St     New St   
City1             m          r             t
City2             x          z             y
Interest         Yes         No           Yes
High Interest    Yes         No           Yes    
Low Interest     No          No           Yes
Animal           Tiger       Cat         Dog
Color           Green        Blue       Yellow

I tried using :
order = ['Name', 'Street Name', 'City', 'Interest','High Interest','Low Interest', 'Animal', 'Color']
df['order'] = df['col1'].apply(order)
df = df.sort_values(by = 'order').drop(columns = 'order')

However, this created an issue where 'Street Name' rows were coming before 'Name' since 'Name' is in both. Like:
     col1           col2        col3       col4
    Street Name1    Pine St    Crown St    Palm Ave
    Street Name2    Grey St    Tree St     New St   
    Name             Adam       Grace       Julia

How can I order this data frame so that it is in the proper order even if it is present substring for another row?
UPDATE:
I can't explicitly list 'Street Name1', 'Street Name2' since the number at the end could change. For different scenarios, it could be also 'Street Name1', 'Street Name2'.... 'Street Name7'. So I can't explicitly define the numbers.

What are the constraints here? Why do you need to do substring matching rather than change the order list to ['Name', 'Street Name1', 'Street Name2' ... ]  etc. and just match on the exact string?

Is "Street Name" the only one that can have different numbers (i.e. the only one that might not be matched exactly)?

Any row with '1' or '2' at the end can have a difference in numbers

Is there a maximum value that the numbers can have? I assume there is and it's quite low, i.e. you're not going to have City4450050?

Yes, most likely wouldn't go above 20

Then I would suggest using pd.Categorical and just change the order list ['Name', 'Street Name1', ... , 'Street Name20']. Reduces the chances of any unexpected surprises or weird matches if you use patterns.

You could use str.extract with a crafted regex to get the leading parts of the names, then convert to Categorical and sort with sort_values/numpy.lexsort:
import re

pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(order, key=len, reverse=True)))

idx = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(df['col1'].str.extract(f'({pattern})',
                                                      expand=False),
                               categories=order, ordered=True),
                index=df.index).sort_values(kind='stable').index

out = df.reindex(idx)

If you also want to sort based on the part after the keywords as secondary key:
import re
import numpy

order = ['Name', 'Street Name', 'City', 'Interest','High Interest','Low Interest', 'Animal', 'Color']

pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(order, key=len, reverse=True)))
tmp = df['col1'].str.extract(f'({pattern})(.*)')

out = df.iloc[np.lexsort([pd.to_numeric(tmp[1], errors='coerce'),
                          pd.Categorical(tmp[0], categories=order,
                                         ordered=True).codes])]

Output:
            col1     col2      col3      col4
1           Name     Adam     Grace     Julia
2   Street Name1  Pine St  Crown St  Palm Ave
3   Street Name2  Grey St   Tree St    New St
9          City1        m         r         t
8          City2        x         z         y
5       Interest      Yes        No       Yes
7  High Interest      Yes        No       Yes
6   Low Interest       No        No       Yes
0         Animal    Tiger       Cat       Dog
4          Color    Green      Blue    Yellow

Intermediate tmp:
               0  1
0         Animal   
1           Name   
2    Street Name  1
3    Street Name  2
4          Color   
5       Interest   
6   Low Interest   
7  High Interest   
8           City  2
9           City  1


Thanks! This works. However, when there are values in col1 that are greater than 9, it orders like Street Name1, Street Name10, Street Name2. How do I get it so that it's ordered as Street Name1, Street Name2, Street Name10?

@mjoy you can convert the integers to numeric. See update.

We can use the exact strings from your DataFrame in the order list, not partial matches, and then pd.Categorical() instead of apply(). This way, the categorical type respects the exact order we specify.
data = {
    'col1': ['Animal', 'Name', 'Street Name1', 'Street Name2', 'Color', 'Interest', 
             'Low Interest', 'High Interest', 'City2', 'City1'],
    'col2': ['Tiger', 'Adam', 'Pine St', 'Grey St', 'Green', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'x', 'm'],
    'col3': ['Cat', 'Grace', 'Crown St', 'Tree St', 'Blue', 'No', 'No', 'No', 'z', 'r'],
    'col4': ['Dog', 'Julia', 'Palm Ave', 'New St', 'Yellow', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'y', 't']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Your custom order
order = ['Name', 'Street Name1', 'Street Name2', 'City1', 'City2', 
         'Interest', 'High Interest', 'Low Interest', 'Animal', 'Color']

# Create a categorical type with our custom order
df['order'] = pd.Categorical(df['col1'], categories=order, ordered=True)

# Sort the DataFrame and drop the temporary column
df_sorted = df.sort_values('order').drop(columns='order')

print(df_sorted)

Output:
            col1     col2      col3      col4
1           Name     Adam     Grace     Julia
2   Street Name1  Pine St  Crown St  Palm Ave
3   Street Name2  Grey St   Tree St    New St
9          City1        m         r         t
8          City2        x         z         y
5       Interest      Yes        No       Yes
7  High Interest      Yes        No       Yes
6   Low Interest       No        No       Yes
0         Animal    Tiger       Cat       Dog
4          Color    Green      Blue    Yellow

